# How can I convert string to integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I have a database table field of type `string`. The data in that field has values like:

> 1/2014
>
> 2/2014

Now i want to *increase* that field to `3/2014` using `VB.NET`.
Note that `1` and `2` are not a month, it is serial number.

How can i do that?

Comment: Looks like MM/yyyy date to me, not an int.  Try using `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)`.

Comment: you need to increase month of each field  by one?

Answer (score 6):

You aren't doing string-to-integer conversion, you're working with dates.

Assuming your date format is `M/yyyy`, then use this:

```
Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact( myFieldValue, "M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
dateValue = dateValue.AddMonths( 1 )
SaveNewDate( dateValue )
```

Comment: ParseExact requires three arguments

Answer (score 3):

As you have stated that this is **not** a date, you can use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the string to extract the first part and then attempt to parse this into an Integer value:

```
Dim s As String = "2/2014"
Dim serialNo As Integer
If Not Int32.TryParse(s.Split("/"c)(0), serialNo) Then
    'throw an error here because the string was no in the expected format
End If
serialNo += 1
s = serialNo.ToString + s.Substring(s.IndexOf("/"))

Debug.WriteLine(s)
```

Output

```
 3/2014
```

Note that you may want to check that the string contains the `/` character as well before you start.

Even better, store the serial number as a separate `Integer` field in the database to start with.